# How to get structured data in an array in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

Hi there I made this code as example :

```
struct myData{
var payments: Int!
var paymentDate : String!
var itemNumber : String!
              }

var myDataArray = [myData(payments:100, paymentDate: "10/10/2010", itemNumber: "1001"),
               myData(payments:200, paymentDate: "10/10/2010", itemNumber: "1002" ),
               myData(payments:500, paymentDate: "10/10/2010", itemNumber: "2001" ),
               myData(payments:400, paymentDate: "10/10/2010", itemNumber: "3210" ),
               myData(payments:150, paymentDate: "10/10/2010", itemNumber: "1234" ),]
```

What I'm asking for how could I get the results for a specific object for that structure Data. for Example If I want to print all the payments result or specific IndexPath

really I tried hard and I searched hard but without any clear answers

Comment: Yo print a specific you do: myDataArrat[0] and you will print your first value. I you want to print all of them, you can do a foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to print the data, see PEEJWEEJ's answer. If you want an array of, say, all `payments` properties of the individual array entries, 
 use

```
myDataArray.map { $0.payments }
```

which essentially means 'go through each element of `myDataArray`, execute `element.payments` on each of these elements, then build an array with the results'.

By the way, it seems like your properties are always available, i.e. never `nil`. In that case you don't need to add a `!` at the end of the declaration, so

```
struct MyData {
  let payments: Int
  let paymentDate: String
  let itemNumber: String
}
```

would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

`print(myDataArray[0].payments)` would print the first item's payments. (so 100)

If you want to print all of them, you could loop through it like so:
`myDataArray.forEach { print($0.payments) }`

Comment: Thanks for you help dude